# Fetching tweets through tweepy - how many tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I am doing a project on aspect based sentiment analysis from tweets on twitter. I am using tweepy to fetch the tweets. I noticed that I get only a few tweets. What is the maximum number of tweets I can get using tweepy, when a product name is searched? Is there any way I can increase this number? This is the code I am referring to : https://pastebin.com/vqbkFhtf

Comment: Post your working code, to make it more clear.

Comment: @TheManHasNoName https://pastebin.com/vqbkFhtf sir this is the code I'm referring to

Answer (score 1):

The number of tweets will depend on how many people are talking about the product.
Also i would suggest you to use  [twitter streaming API](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html) so that you get the tweets as they appear.